# Official GCP statement about (non) exposure to Solarwinds Orion vulnerability?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We've tried to find something like an "official" statement from Google about GCP's exposure (or lack thereof) to the recent Solarwinds Orion hack.  We're a GCP customer but don't have a support package.  Other than purchasing a support package only for the purpose of obtaining a statement (assuming support would provide something), any other channels?

Comment: I would be quite surprised if Google used this product anywhere. They have built custom monitoring from the ground up over the years, as nothing else would really work at their scale.

Answer (score 0):

This is what opening a support case is for, getting answers that are not publicly available.

As a guess, unlikely that Google uses Orion, not compatible with Google's inexpensive large scale custom hardware and software stacks.